# Dev Database connection persisting on production environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2005, web-config

as the title suggests i'm having a little problem with a persisting database connection. Here, we have 2 databases, one for dev and testing and the oficial, production one. We used to change manually the different connection strings when testing and deploying and sometimes a strange error happened. When we stopped the dev database suddenly the entire production application stopped to work, saying that the SQL connection was lost. But the web.config was pointing to production not testing environment!

After some research, we found the web.config transformation and thought that would solve our problem. It didn't. The problem still persists as if our application is tight to the dev environment even when our web.config doesn't make a single reference to it.

To make things clearer, i'll post the connection strings, the transformation and the latest SQL error that happened (when we limited the dev database to single-user for some updates), plus the way we connect it to our DBML (L2SQL).

CONNECTION STRINGs

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

    <!--ConnectionString Central-->
    <add name="OperationsBD" connectionString="Data Source=DEVSERVER\DEV;Initial Catalog=OPERATION;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=lab;Password=devPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="AnalisysBD" connectionString="Data Source=DEVSERVER\DEV;Initial Catalog=ANALISYS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=lab;Password=devPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> 

<!--Production ConnectionString-->
    <!--<add name="OperationsDB" connectionString="Data Source=PRODSERVER\COMPANY;Initial Catalog=OPERATION;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=company;Password=prodPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="AnalisysDB" connectionString="Data Source=PRODSERVER\COMPANY;Initial Catalog=ANALISYS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=company;Password=prodPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>-->
```

WEB.CONFIG TRANSFORMATION (PRODUCTION)

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="OperationsDB" 
        connectionString="Data Source=PRODSERVER\COMPANY;Initial Catalog=OPERATION;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=company;Password=prodPassword" 
           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>

      <add name="AnalisysDB"
        connectionString="Data Source=PRODSERVER\COMPANY;Initial Catalog=ANALISYS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=company;Password=prodPassword"
           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

WEB.CONFIG TRANSFORMATION (DEV)

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="OperationsDB"
        connectionString="Data Source=DEVSERVER\DEV;Initial Catalog=OPERATION;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=lab;Password=devPassword"
           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>

      <add name="AnalisysDB"
        connectionString="Data Source=DEVSERVER\DEV;Initial Catalog=ANALISYS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=lab;Password=devPassword"
           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

SQL ERROR (single-user limitation on dev environment)

```
Cannot open database "operation" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'lab'.
```

And lastly, the way we connect it to the LINQ to SQL DBML

```
public partial class OperationDataContext
    {
        private const string OPERATION_CONN_STRING = "OperationsDB";
        public OperationDataContext()
            : base(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[OPERATION_CONN_STRING].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }
    }

    public partial class AnalisysDataContext
    {
        private const string ANALISYS_CONN_STRING = "AnalisysDB";
        public AnalisysDataContext()
            : base(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ANALISYS_CONN_STRING].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your base web.config connection strings inside the <connectionString> element?  Is the element a direct descendant of <configuration>?  The elements and paths have to match exactly between the main config and config transformation files

Comment: @Tommy, yes it is. The web.config transform is working flawlessly and that's even one more reason for my ignorance on this problem. When i check my produtcion web.config after the transform, it doesn't have any reference to my dev DB, otherwise my clients wouldn't be able to use the app, since the connection would point to a wrong DB. My guess is that VS is generating some undercover code which is referencing the dev DB.

Answer (score 0):

This may be just a typo, but I did notice that the "Name" on Dev was "OperationsBD" and "AnaylsisBD", but the Transforms are set to match on name of "OperationsDB" and "AnaylsisDB".  If this isn't a typo, it would never match, thus never replacing the connection strings.

Comment: I changed the DB names and made a mistake while doing it. Saw it when i was reading my question again and fixed it. But rest assured that the transformation is working correctly and the problem still persists.

Comment: Ahh, well my answer was moot then.